# Weird behavior of derivative D[] function in v11

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced after version 9.0.1, in or before version 11.0, fixed before 12.3.**

---

Recently I noticed that a code developed in v13 was giving unexpected errors about the formatting of matrices in v11 (in an older machine), and I was able to isolate the issue to a weird behavior by the derivative function `D[]` which, when applied to a constant vector, transforms it to a scalar!

A minimal example is as follows: Let's take the 2nd derivative a vector with respect to some other parameter. In versions 9, 12.3 and 13 (that I checked) this gives the expected result:

```
D[{t, t, t}, {x, 2}]
(* {0,0,0} *)
```

but in v11:

```
D[{t, t, t}, {x, 2}]
(* 0 *)
```

This has the undesired side-effect that it converts vectors/matrices to scalars or even worse, reduces the order of parts of a matrix thus giving errors when doing matrix algebra!

The obvious work-around in v11 is to do the derivatives sequentially:

```
D[{t, t, t}, x]
D[%, x]
(* {0,0,0} *)
(* {0,0,0} *)
```

or

```
D[D[{t, t, t}, x], x]
(* {0,0,0} *)
```

**Edit**: Thanks to @Nasser: The help in v11 says:

[image]

> For lists, D[{Subscript[f, 1],Subscript[f, 2],[Ellipsis]},x] is
> equivalent to {D[Subscript[f, 1],x],D[Subscript[f, 2],x],[Ellipsis]} recursively. »

Thus, this is probably a bug in `D[]` in v11, but I'm hesitant to call it as such until verified by the community. Also, it only appears in v11 as far as I can tell, but I wasn't able to find something in this Stack by searching (apologies if I missed anything).

**Edit**: Thanks to @Bob Hanlon for another workaround for v11 for vectors:

```
D[#, {x, 2}] & /@ {t, t, t}
(* {0,0,0} *)
```

and for matrices (after specifying a level):

```
Map[D[#, {x, 2}] &, {{t, t, t}, {x^2, x^2, x^2}}, {2}]
(* {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 2, 2}} *)
```

PS All tests were done on Windows 10.

Comment: current behavior is according to help. It says **For lists, D[{f1,f2,...},x] is equivalent to {D[f1,x],D[f2,x],...} recursively.** may be this is not how it was in V 11 and it was changed sometime after that.

Comment: I just checked and in v11 it says the same exactly, so the behaviour in v11 is unexpected I think.

Comment: Or, as a workaround, use `Map`, i.e., `D[#, {x, 2}] & /@ {t, t, t}`

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks :-)

Comment: However, it seems it fails for matrices, I'll edit the question

Comment: `Function[f, D[f, {x, 2}], Listable][matrix]` should work on matrices, vectors, functions, and so forth. -- I doubt the community will be able to really vet an issue in such an old version. Since it seems to work right in all recent versions, I doubt many will find it worth pursuing.

Comment: For matrices specify a level, `Map[D[#, {x, 2}] &, {{t, t, t}, {x^2, x^2, x^2}}, {2}]`

Comment: @Goofy I agree, it was more of a curiosity to be honest. Since (I think) it's clear it's a bug, should I add at least the bug tag?

Comment: I think it's safe to call it a bug. Edited. BTW, in version 11 `Unprotect[D];
D[expr_List, var__] := D[#, var] & /@ expr;
Protect[D]` will fix the bug, I guess.

Comment: @xzczd Fantastic, thanks so much!